# How to override ProducesAttribute that is defined in controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-7.0

Is there a way of overriding the inherited ProducesAttribute from a controller in a method?

I have next Controller

```cs
[Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
public class IdentityController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> Get()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and swagger generates two options for the MediaType but I'd like to only display the pdf option.

[image]

I'm asking because I have a lot of endpoints that return `application/json` and only few with `pdf` son I'm trying to create a global CustomBaseController with `Produce("application/json")` and only override it for some endpoints

Comment: Have you tried splitting into two containers with different `[Produces(...)]`. One for download and one for JSON usage?

Comment: Without the `Produces(...)` defined at the controller level ? I'm asking because I have a lot of endpoints that return `application/json` and only few with `pdf` son I'm trying to create a global `CustomBaseController` with `Produce("application/json")`  and only override it for some endpoints

Comment: @Carlos Do you really need ProducesAttribute? It produces what produces and if you add the attribute it will not start to produce something else

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try with IOperationFilter,For example,I tried as below:

```
public class MediaTypeFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            var formats = context.ApiDescription.SupportedResponseTypes[0].ApiResponseFormats;
            if(formats.Where(x=>x.MediaType== MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf).Count() == 0)
            {
                var responsetype = context.ApiDescription.SupportedResponseTypes[0].Type;

                var schema = context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(responsetype, context.SchemaRepository);
                var type = new OpenApiMediaType() { Schema = schema };
                var openapiresponse = new OpenApiResponse()
                {
                    Content = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiMediaType>(){
                    { MediaTypeNames.Application.Json,type}
                }
                };
                operation.Responses.Clear();
                operation.Responses.Add("200", openapiresponse);
            }          
        }
    }
```

regist it in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(x=>x.OperationFilter<MediaTypeFilter>());
```

Remove`[Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]` on your controller,

Result:
[image]